# Facing issue with angularjs websocket

Tags: angularjs, websocket

Am new to angularjs and trying to work with websoket.
I've used ngroute module and existing pages are getting routed and works fine. when i include websocket dependencies am facing some issue and not able to identify the reason.
Below i've attached the code which i used in factory, module and includes.

```
var angularmodule= angular.module('mydemo', ['ui.router','ngWebSocket']);



factoryService =  function($websocket) {
      // Open a WebSocket connection 
      var dataStream = $websocket('ws://localhost:8081/webapplication/greeting');

      var collection = [];

      dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
        collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
      });

      var methods = {
        collection: collection,
        get: function() {
          dataStream.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'get' }));
        }
      };

      return methods;
    };

angularmodule.factory('myfactroyService',factoryService);
```

In html,

Referred the below website
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-websocket

error in chrome console

**angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=mydemo&p1=Error%3A%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)**

Please guide me to continue with angularjs websocket
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Are there console errors?

Comment: Am getting the issue from angular.js as injection failure

angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=mydemo&p1=Error%3A%…

Comment: Can you paste the full error in your question please?

Comment: @gmustudent, I've added the error in question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for that. It's not too descriptive b/c your using angular.min.js. While in development you should try using the unminified version of angular. It'll make your error messages make a lot more sense providing line numbers and exact problems to what is going down! Can you swap to the unminified angular by chance?

Comment: am using
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124082/discussion-between-gmustudent-and-krishna-moorthy-seetha-raman).